# Can someone please explain the significance of the subscript 2 on this picture?

Tags: convergence-divergence

[[image]]

Does the subscript here refer to the L2 norm? In the right hand side, are they saying that this is are squaring the square root of the difference in squares? Is convergence here reffering to the real minimum of the function "f"?

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, yes & yes. I do not think the hypotheses are enough to ensure that a minimiser ($x^*$ above) exists.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Why do you think that? I would be curious to hear your thoughts!

Comment: $f(x) = x$ has no minimum. There is often a condition such as the Hessian satisfies $f''(x) \ge \mu I$ for some $\mu >0$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I wonder why this point wasn't brought up here?